# how creat urdf.rviz file for my urdf file?

Tags: urdf, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i using SolidWorks to URDF Exporter and creat urdf file . how creat urdf.rviz  ?
it is my display.launch :

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" />
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find wrist)/urdf/wrist.urdf" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="true" />
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
 <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find wrist)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
</launch>
```

i have urdf file and meshes file but i do not have urdf.rviz file .
how creat urdf.rviz  file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249076/how-creat-urdf.rviz--file-for-my-urdf-file?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `.rviz` files contain configuration information for RViz (which displays to load, how they are configured, etc).

You can create one by just starting RViz, configuring it as you would like (ie: add some displays, perhaps for *Robot Model* if you want to visualise your robot's state, etc), then click `File -> Save Config As`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0